# flash builder 4.7 AIR app how to get iPhone time and date?

Tags: iphone, ios, time, air

is there anyway to access time on the Iphone(or other ios devices) from AIR app made with flash builder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access time like on every other device. Use this code:

```
var currentTime:Date = new Date();
trace(currentTime);
```

You need to call new Date() anytime you want the actual time.

See [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Date.html) for details.

Works with the iOS-Simulator and should work on the device as well.

Comment: ok, thanks! Is there a list of all device related commands for air for ios?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the Date() class.
(Maybe I misunderstood your question)